Discrete vertical lines when plotting predicted values against actual values in random forest
I am using random forest for my data set in which my response is continuous and all features are as factors. When I plot predicted value against actual value the plot shows discrete vertical lines, as shown in the following picture. Does anyone know how can I fix that?


Start by considering one binary predictor (feature), for which only two distinct predicted outcome values are possible, leading to two distinct vertical lines on a plot like yours.
As you increase the number of binary predictors, more distinct predicted values are possible, but the discreteness never disappears. It just becomes less obvious.
That is true for any method for which the predicted value will be the same when all the features have the same values. It isn't peculiar to random forests. It's not a problem that you can fix with what you are doing; you can reduce it as you have done by using several features, or you can reduce it further by using continuous features too.
Judging by your plot your model isn't doing very well any way, so on other grounds you may need to rethink your model, or ride with  an output that is hard to predict.

If I understand correctly, you mean that this is not the right algorithm for my data?

No; I am not saying that. I can't have a useful opinion on how you should approach predicting one variable from others when you don't say anything precise about your data. Your problem may resemble trying to predict people's heights or weights from (male, female); (young, old); (manual worker; office worker); and so on. Or it may be quite different.

I think your axis titles (labels) are the wrong way round.  Predicted is on the $x$ axis. Actual is on the $y$ axis.
